# how remove or replace string tag with blank in JSON

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.taxmanntechnologies.com/">[{"INT_ID":"102010000000000015","INT_Section_ID":"102120000000000069", "Section_No":"Section - 16 ","Heading":" Functions of Central Board"}]</string>
```

i have This data i want to 
remove `<string xmlns="http://www.taxmanntechnologies.com/"> </String >`,
so that i can get JSON Data can any one please tell me how to remove it so that i can parse it.

Comment: can u please tell me code ..

Comment: I have to remove <string xmlns="http://www.taxmanntechnologies.com/">  </String > so that i can get JSON data and Parse it

Comment: If you exactly know the string, you can call a string replace with a blank string

Comment: ok can u please set me in string  within double " "

Comment: <string xmlns="http://www.taxmanntechnologies.com/">

Comment: you load your "String" the whole thing including this text and call replace. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: yes i know But when i user str.replace(" <string xmlns="http://www.taxmanntechnologies.com/">   "  " ") then its got Error in double qute i m asking how i ll set <string xmlns="http://www.taxmanntechnologies.com/">  in to " "(double quote ) please set it

Comment: str.replace(" <string xmlns=\"taxmanntechnologies.com/\">; " " ")

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it "right" you need to parse the xml, popular xml parsing techiques/libraries are SAX and DOM, SAX is more eventdriven and a bit trickier to use, and DOM is slower, especially for large xml documents.

For this usecase I would use an DOM parser, roughly like this:

```
File fXmlFile = new File("c:\\file.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("string");
String json =  nList.item(0).getNodeValue();
```

Comment: how i ll set <string xmlns="http://www.taxmanntechnologies.com/"> its in double " "